# Is $\lim_{n \to \infty} (1 - n^{-a}x)^n = 0$ when $0 < a < 1$?

Tags: limits, convergence-divergence

I'm trying to find the value of the following when $0<a<1$, $\forall x > 0$

$$
\lim_{n \to \infty} (1 - n^{-a}x)^n
$$

---

What I **tried**:

$$
\begin{aligned}
\lim_{n \to \infty} (1 - n^{-a}x)^n &= \lim_{n \to \infty} (1 - n^{-a}x)^{n^{a}n^{-a+1}} \\
&= \Big[ \lim_{n \to \infty} (1 - n^{-a}x)^{n^{a}} \Big]^{n^{-a+1}} \\
&= \lim_{n \to \infty}\Big( e^{-x} \Big)^{n^{-a+1}} \\
&= \infty \\
&\Big(\because \lim_{n \to \infty} n^{-a+1} \to \infty \text{ when } 0 < a < 1 \Big)
\end{aligned}
$$

---

But I confuse, since whenever I try approximating it with **Wolfram Alpha** with $a = \frac{1}{2}$, I get 0. Is there anyone to help me out?

(In Wolfram Alpha, I typed the following)

*lim (1 - n^(-(1/2)) * x)^n n->infinity*

Comment: Well, if $e^{-x}<1$ then this will converge to $0$

Comment: @asdf, oh, I just edited the range : $x > 0$

Comment: Why don't you believe Alpha ?

Comment: That's what I said: $x>0 \Leftrightarrow e^{-x}<1$

Comment: It's clearly not true that $\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}x\cdot e^x=x\cdot \lim_{x\rightarrow 0}e^x=x\cdot 1=x$. However you have don't something similar by taking the limit inside an expression that incorporates an $n$ on the outside.

Comment: @Robert The OP has done nothing wrong up to the final answer.  The limit error you discussed is not at all analogous.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For $x> 0:$ Consider the logarithm of the expression:

(1).For $y\ne 0$ we have $\lim_{y\to 0}\frac {\log (1+y)}{y}=1.$

(2). For $n$ large enough that $|n^{-a}x|<1$ we have $$\log ((1-xn^{-a})^n)=n\cdot 
 (-xn^{-a})\cdot \frac {\log (1-xn^{-a})} {-xn^{-a}}.$$ By (1), this $\to -\infty$ as $n\to \infty,$ when $0<a<1$ and $x> 0.$